# Cannot use JpegBitmapEncoder in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

While testing Azure Functions, I wrote the following blob-triggered code:

```
#r "System.Drawing"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "WindowsBase"

using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public static void Run(Stream imageStream, string providerName, string imageKey, string extension, Stream outputStream, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Function triggered by blob\n Name:{imageKey} \n Size: {imageStream.Length} Bytes");

    var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    BitmapFrame image = decoder.Frames[0];

    double ratio = Math.Min(200 / (double)image.PixelWidth, 200 / (double)image.PixelHeight);
    var target = new TransformedBitmap(image, new ScaleTransform(ratio, ratio, 0, 0));
    image = BitmapFrame.Create(target);

    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 85 };
    encoder.Frames.Add(image);
    //encoder.Save(outputStream);
}
```

If I uncomment the last line, I get the following error:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessImageTest.
>   mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   PresentationCore: Specified method is not supported.

I don't understand why `JpegBitmapEncoder` is available if one cannot use the `Save`method...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the following solution:

`run.csx`

```
#r "System.Drawing"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

public static void Run(Stream imageStream, string imageName, string extension, CloudBlockBlob outputBlob, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Function triggered by blob\n Name:{imageName} \n Size: {imageStream.Length} Bytes");

    var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(imageStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat | BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile, BitmapCacheOption.None);
    BitmapFrame image = decoder.Frames[0];

    double ratio = Math.Min(200 / (double)image.PixelWidth, 200 / (double)image.PixelHeight);
    var target = new TransformedBitmap(image, new ScaleTransform(ratio, ratio, 0, 0));
    image = BitmapFrame.Create(target);

    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 85 };
    encoder.Frames.Add(image);

    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(outputStream);
        outputStream.Position = 0;
        outputBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        outputBlob.UploadFromStream(outputStream);
    }
}
```

`function.json`

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "imageStream",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input-container/{imageName}.{extension}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "output-container/{imageName}.jpg",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
      "direction": "inout"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably due to sandbox resterictions regarding access of `win32k.sys` \ `GDI+` APIs. 
You can look here for more details about the sandbox https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions

I can also verify that, but I'll need the app name (you can share it either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately) but in general graphics APIs won't work reliably on app service.

Comment: Thank you very much. It would be great if you could indeed confirm where the problem comes from. Here are my app's details: ``2017-08-28T07:39:15.489 Function started (Id=4d286e48-d80c-4b7f-b3fc-2c1cf30734e4)``. Region: Western Europe.

Comment: Also, what would you advise for a simple blob-triggered image resizer like what I'm trying to achieve?