# Bitmap Transparent pixel to white in Azure Function (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I know the simple way of doing this but unfortunately because of some sandbox restrictions in Azure functions the code below doesn't work:

```
        private Stream Transparent2Color(PDFiumBitmap input, Color target)
        {
            try
            {
                Image inputImage = Bitmap.FromStream(input.AsBmpStream());

                Bitmap result = new Bitmap(inputImage.Width, input.Height);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, inputImage.Size);
                using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                {
                    G.Clear(target);
                    G.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(inputImage, rect);
                }

                return ToStream(result, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return input.AsBmpStream();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas how to change the transparent pixels to white without using Graphics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916363/1537195

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use JpegBitmapEncoder in Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885567/cannot-use-jpegbitmapencoder-in-azure-function)

Comment: Hello @JanuszNowak thank you for looking into this. Does that JPEG having black background or white background? My current problem is the following, I'm having a cognitive skillset, I convert PDFs to pages and then to Bitmap then I save it to a blob container then the next skill which came default from the Skillset I use converts the IMages to JPG for image cracking which draws black background for the image which doesn't look okay on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work on a plan which is not isolated as Sandbox environment is having those limitations only :

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

Also it is important to have your Azure Function on V3.

For cheaper plans you may go with third party libraries which are not dependent on System.Drawing:

https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp